# Responsive canvas content to fit different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element with 3 circles that is shown well and fit on large screens. But with smaller screens, The content goes outside of the canvas.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      context = canv.getContext('2d');

    //Set canvas width and height equals to screen width and height
    canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    
//Draw circles
for(let i = 300; i < 950; i+=300){
    if(i < 900){
        context.fillRect(i + 150, 350, 100, 10);
    }
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(i + 50, 350, 100, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Here is a live fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ep3yjs5q

How to make the 3 circles responsive? Can I use percentages for dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use percentages. Based on the code you've provided I assume your calculations for the size and position of the circles is based on a canvas that has a width of 1300 pixels.

Let's do the math:

- your circle's diameter is 200 pixels | 200 / 1300 = 0.1539
- the spacing between them is 300 pixels | 300 / 1300 = 0.2307

With this information we can calculate the appropriate width/height/spacing for the canvas's actual size:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  context = canv.getContext('2d');

canv.height = window.innerHeight;
canv.width = window.innerWidth;

let diameter = (200 / 1300) * canv.width;
let spacing = (300 / 1300) * canv.width;
let barHeight = (30 / 1300) * canv.height;
let startX = canv.width / 2 - spacing;
let startY = canv.height / 2;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i < 2) {
    context.fillRect(startX + i * spacing + diameter / 2, startY, spacing - diameter, barHeight);
  }

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(startX + i * spacing, startY, diameter / 2, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: #dddddd"></canvas>
```